Set page layout to produce a three page pdf
I have a macro which creates PDFs from a sheet.
Depending on the laptop of the user, the page breaks and size is different.
I read that is due to the screen resolution/Windows zoom, which seems to be the problem, as each user has different scale % in their Display settings in Windows.
I am trying to set it in VBA.
With snQ.PageSetup
    .Zoom = False
    .FitToPagesTall = 1
    .FitToPagesWide = 3
End With
snQ.ResetAllPageBreaks
Set snQ.HPageBreaks(2).Location = snQ.Range("B74")
Set snQ.HPageBreaks(2).Location = snQ.Range("B146")

This sets the printing area to three pages.
However the page breaks between the three pages don't change (or change to wrong place) depending on each person.
Seems when I apply the pagebreaks, the page layout changes from 1-3 pages to a %, as if I go to the page setting, is no longer 1-3, but zoom 83% (in my case).

At the end I opted for separating each page (each in its own sheet) then when creating pdf selecting all 3 before pdf is created.
This creates 3 continuous sheets in one pdf.
Each sheet is marked as 1 page width, 1 page height.
This method seems to work for all users, regardless of its windows zoom...

PageSetup.Zoom property
Returns or sets a Variant value that represents a percentage (between 10 and 400 percent) by which Microsoft Excel will scale the worksheet for printing.

snQ.PageSetup.Zoom = False


False evaluates as 0 which is invalid.  You could try 100 which is 100% (normal view).

snQ.PageSetup.Zoom = 100


This removes all Page Breaks

snQ.ResetAllPageBreaks


With no programmatic page breaks snQ.HPageBreaks.Count = 0
I guess the OP is using On Error Resume Next because this throws an error:

Set snQ.HPageBreaks(2).Location = snQ.Range("B74")


Here is the proper way to add page breaks:

snQ.HPageBreaks.Add Before:=snQ.Range("B74")
snQ.HPageBreaks.Add Before:=snQ.Range("B146")


But this is adding horizontal page breaks and the code is setting the print area to 3 pages wide.FitToPagesWide = 3 and only one page tall .FitToPagesTall = 1.  Use VPageBreaks for vertical page breaks.
If can't figure it out, consider appending each page to a pdf.  Let me know if you need clarification on this.

Hi, I added the snQ.HPageBreaks.Add Before:=snQ.Range("B74") etc as you mention.
This has no effect..the dotted blue line continues on the same place, does not move.
It does move to the right location if moved manually though.
p.s. the code I added (which was wrong) was created by the macro recorder, manually moving the line to the correct place. But I guess the correct way is as you stated (although unfortunately does not work)
I will appreciate additional info on PDF appending...that might be a better solution.
At the end the aim is to save sheet as a 3 page PDF (continuous 3 pages)

I appreciate your response.  Good luck!

perhaps something like:
snQ.PageSetup.PrintArea = "$A$1:$K74"

snQ.PrintOut

snQ.PageSetup.PrintArea = "$A$75:$K146"

snQ.PrintOut

...


Thanks. I've tested your method and this seems to print each page separately.
The idea is to end up with a 3 page PDF
